# Why the following bitwise operation will generate a Numeric Overflow?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have the following rather straight forward bit-wise operation

```
final int mask = ((1 << 31) - 1);
```

However, I'm really can't figure out why, Android Studio (IntelliJ) IDE will give me `Numeric Overflow` warning

[image]

---

I did a quick run in desktop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int mask = ((1 << 31) - 1);
    System.out.println(mask);               // 2147483647
    System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);  // 2147483647
}
```

It seems fine to me. However, I was puzzling, why IDE gives me such warning?

Comment: using intellij 2018.2 - I don't have the warning...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that it was an issue in IntelliJ 2018.1. Here is explanation,

> [IDEA-182699](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2018.2+182.3208.16+Release+Notes)  Numeric overflow: add an option to ignore if left
>   bitwise shift result makes number negative - [Its question](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-182699)

---

The compiler gets `1` as `int`.  What about?

```
final int mask = (int)((1L << 31) - 1);
```

Mathematically,

```
  1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    (1 << 31)
  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111    (-1)
-----------------------------------------
1 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111    +
^

  0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111    (truncate)
```

Answer (score 2):

You shifted into the sign bit: 1<<31 = 2<sup>31</sup> and Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2<sup>31</sup> - 1.
Hence there is (sign) overflow, you actually got Integer.MIN_VALUE. Further subtracting 1 can be called an overflow (carry) too, and probably triggered the error.