# Cannot understand the reason for warning

Tags: c, gcc

Please consider the following simple program. When I compile this with `compile : gcc -o test test.c` I get lots of  `warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]` warnings. I don't understand why I get these warnings.
Note that the variable Q is 31 bits long. I have tried typecasting to `uint64_t` but without any solution. Interestingly if I remove the `#define Q ( (1<<k1) - (1<<k2) + 1 )` and write the numericalvalue of Q as `uint64_t Q=2130706433;` Then most of the warnings messages are gone but still I get one warning message for `m=( m& (k1_minus_one) ) + ( ((m>>k1)<<k2) - (m>>k1) );`. If I put the numerical value the code works as expected in spite of the warnings, however with the former `#define` statement the code does not work. I am using `gcc (Ubuntu 6.5.0-2ubuntu1~16.04) 6.5.0 20181026`
Can you please tell me what could be the possible source of this problem and possible solutions?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//compile : gcc -o test test.c

#define N 1024
#define k1 31
#define k2 24

void mul_mod_large(uint64_t *a, uint64_t *b, uint64_t *c);
void get_arr(uint64_t *a, uint64_t q, uint64_t n);

#define k1_minus_one ( (1<<k1)-1 )
#define Q ( (1<<k1) - (1<<k2) + 1 )
//uint64_t Q=2130706433;

void main(){

}

void mul_mod_large(uint64_t *a, uint64_t *b, uint64_t *c){

    uint64_t i, m;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        m=a[i]*b[i];
        while(m>(2*Q)){
            m=( m& (k1_minus_one) ) + ( ((m>>k1)<<k2) - (m>>k1) );
        }
        c[i]=m;
        if(m>=Q){
            c[i]=m-Q;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe add `U` to the define: `#define k1_minus_one ( (1U<<k1)-1 )`

Comment: To expand on what @pmg said by [default literals in C are `int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/expressions#Constants_and_literals) so you need to tell the compiler explicitly to treat it differently, particularly in a macro which is not reduced to a constant at compile time (technically it can be, but it's not the same as C++ `constexpr`)

Comment: I think it comes down to the type of the expression 1<<k being int, because 1 is an int. I think you need ((int64_t)1)<<k which will be of type int64_t

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the following bitwise operation will generate a Numeric Overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51651590/why-the-following-bitwise-operation-will-generate-a-numeric-overflow)

Comment: You could use `#define Q ( (UINT32_C(1) << k1) - (UINT32_C(1) << k2) + 1)` (`UINT32_C(1)` is likely to expand to `1U` (or `1u`) assuming your `unsigned int` type is at least 32 bits wide.)

Comment: `Q` may be 31 bits long, but one of the intermediate values is 32 bits long. (The same is the case for `k1_minus_one`.)

Comment: The default type of an integer literal is the smallest type that will hold the value.  It will be an `unsigned long long` if need be.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for the help. I didn't know the default was 32 bits signed integer. As @IanAbbott suggested if I put `U` after the `1`'s the problem is solved.

Comment: @RaymondChen yes that is close.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers in a `signed` 32 bit numer in two's complement varie from `-2^31`  to `2^31 - 1`.
You are using the subexpression `(1 << 31)` which is effectively equivalent to `2^31`, which is one plus than the maximum `int` you can store in your computer.  Even if you later subtract one, the partial result `(1 << 31)` is out of range. Unluckily, signed numbers overflow is **Undefined Behaviour in C**, so you can get the desired result, or you can receive a completely different behaviour (like crashing or aborting your program).  That is the reason for the warning you get.  You can get the maximum number in other ways, but the most effective is to simply use `0x7fffffff`, or

```
#include <limits.h>
...
INT_MAX  /* this is very safe :) */
```

or

```
(((1 << 30) - 1) << 1) + 1)
```

(this last example builds `2^31 - 1` by multiplying by 2 the number `2^30 - 1` and adding one to the result, and that's safe)

Answer (score 0):

As many suggested the problem arose due to the default limit of C for #define constants which is int32. So If I put `U` after the `1`'s the problem is solved.

```
#define k1_minus_one ( (1U<<k1)-1 )
#define Q ( (1U<<k1) - (1U<<k2) + 1 )
```

The above code gives no warnings and runs without errors.

As mentioned in the comments by @Ian Abbott, instead of putting U after 1s writing UINT32_C(1) gives a better and more generic soultion.

Comment: The limit has nothing to do with `#define` as such. Any unsuffixed integer constant that is representable by type `int` (the constant `1` in this case) will have type `int`. The `u` suffix forces it to have an unsigned integer type, so `1u` will have type `unsigned int` since the value is representable by `unsigned int`. Also note that these shifts by 31 and 24 won't work on platforms where `int` is 16 bits wide. You'd need to use `1UL` for those platforms. `UINT32_C(1)` should work either way because it would expand to either `1U` or `1UL` as required for the platform.

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood first time. I have updated the answer.